# How to build an iPOD app in xcode 3.2.6

Tags: ios, xcode, ipod-touch

I am just starting out trying to build an app with xcode. For now, I have to use xcode 3.2.6. How can I build an app for iPOD? When selecting a template for my project I select Window-based application, but under "Product" I can only choose between iPAD and iPHONE. I am tasked with creating an app that will run on iPODs, so I am confused on this point. Almost everything I have seen high and low refers only to iPhone or iPad. Please explain. Thanks!

Comment: Noah's answer is right on target. Just choose iPhone and your app will work on both iPhone/iPod. Just make sure that you only use iPod compatible SDK's.

Comment: @TommieC. What are iPod compatible SDKs? All iOS SDKs work on the iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch.

Comment: @Elkon using Xcode 3 is a waste of time. It's terribly out of date. Most of what you learn will be obsolete.

Comment: @rmaddy Essentially I am referencing access to the different hardware capabilities that are not available on iPod's.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you’re talking about an [iPod touch](http://www.apple.com/ipod/) rather than a [nano](http://www.apple.com/ipod-nano/) or [shuffle](http://www.apple.com/ipod-shuffle/) (neither of which has a third-party SDK), you should be using an iPhone target. The distinction between that and an iPad one in Xcode is entirely about screen size, and every iPod touch has had a screen the size of an iPhone’s.